# Adding Status value dynamically in google sheet using App Script

Tags: api, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem, I want to put an status column that returns completed when my transaction is done. I am using App Script. Here is my code.

```
function myonEdit(e){
var ss = e.source; //Get the spreadsheet
var cell = e.range; //Get the range of the edited cell
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet(); //Get the modified sheet
var row = cell.getRow();
var col = cell.getColumn();
  
//valid cell are within A2:E. If row ==1 or col > 5 do nothing
if(row==1 || col > 5){
    return;
}

//Get the current row's first 5 columns
//Change 2-d array to 1-d array using flat()
var rowValues = sheet.getRange(row,1,1,5).getDisplayValues().flat();
if(rowValues.filter(String).length == 5){
  
   var amount = parseInt(rowValues[0]);
   var email = rowValues[1]; //get value row 1
   var snumber = rowValues[2]; //get value row2
   var esubject = rowValues[3]; //get value row3
   var emessage = rowValues[4]; //getvalue row4

   Logger.log(amount);
   Logger.log(email);
   Logger.log(snumber);
   Logger.log(esubject);
   Logger.log(emessage);

    var dataRequestPost = {
    "amount": amount,
    "email": {
    "recipient_email": email,
    "subject": esubject,
    "message": emessage
   },
    "ref": {
    "order_id": "string",
    "email": email,
    "id1": "string",
    "id2": "string",
    "phone_number": snumber
   },
  "add_to_blacklist": false
      
   };
  }

}
```

[image]

Comment: var rUrl = encodeURI('https://data.seller.tools/api/v1/USD');
   var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(rUrl, {
    "method": "post",
    "contentType": "application/json",
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    },
    "payload": JSON.stringify(dataRequestPost)
  });
  
  var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(object);

Comment: I just want to add 1 column that outputs completed if my transaction succeded

Comment: where do you set the other data? Your code does not send any data back to the sheet. I would suggest you provide the full code so we know how to link the input and the output. Also make sure to understand that `onEdit` triggers upon **user** events.

Comment: Yes correct. That's what I want to achieve

Comment: I just want to have another column that returns completed after the transaction script. Please help me with. I didn't put all the codes cause I have an error on stackoverflow ask question

Answer (score 1):

You want to add "Completed" in column F after you have fetched the response. Add this code inside `if(rowValues.filter(String).length == 5)` after the transaction is done:

```
if(object.length>0){
    sheet.getRange(row,6).setValue("Completed");
}
```

where `sheet` is the active sheet and `row` is the active row as you have correctly defined in the beginning of the script. The number six indicates column F.

I am not sure what is the resulting `object` but you can check if the data you get back is empty or not and mark the status as completed only if it non-empty.

Otherwise use only `sheet.getRange(row,6).setValue("Completed");`